# Multiple AngularJS currency formats, using i18n (Euro, DE)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, gruntjs, internationalization, currency

My angular app needs to display currencies in different formats for example: `$`, `￡`, `2.105,10€` - euro sign after + different separators - which can be achieved by including the i18n `angular-locale_de-de.js` variant.

The problem is I have to display the format based on the JSON's locale value, which happens once the app has initialized, so the currency remains the default regardless of what the JSON says and there doesn't seem to be a way to display the currency as - `$12,000` + the `i18n docs` say that you can only use one locale.

A common practice is to use `angular-locale- + $localevar +.js` in the index file, again my app doesn't know about the locale until the ajax response and uses `grunt` to build the app. how do I tackle this problem?

Any alternate libraries I could use? really frustrated with how difficult angular makes it to handle multiple formats.

Here's a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/awsd2s5r/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only handle a few locales and don't mind the overhead, just include every locale file needed and use the plugin [angular-dynamic-locale](https://github.com/lgalfaso/angular-dynamic-locale) to reload the language once you received the ajax response by doing something like :

```
tmhDynamicLocale.set(ajax_reply.locale)
```

If you really do care about performance, you could additionally load needed locales on the fly using a filter like this one :

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular.module('app.filter').filter('loadScript', [ '$q', function($q) {
        var loaded = [];
        return function get(link) {
            if (loaded.indexOf(link) !== -1)
                return {};
            loaded.push(link);

            var deferred = $q.defer();

            var s = document.createElement('script');
            s.type = 'text/javascript';
            s.src = link;
            s.async = true;
            s.onreadystatechange = s.onload = function() {
                var state = s.readyState;
                if (!state)
                    deferred.resolve();
                else
                    deferred.reject();
            };

            document.body.appendChild(s);

            return deferred.promise;
        };
    }]);

})();
```

Comment: Absolute legend, thanks a lot for pointing me to that plugin! : D

Comment: The only problem with clubbing all locales in one file is that, only the last locale gets loaded and it cannot be changed from that file dynamically. Loading a new file works. Anyway to have them loaded in one file?

Comment: Don't put all your locales in one file, just load every locale you need : see the example in the repo : http://lgalfaso.github.io/angular-dynamic-locale/app.js